# text inverted in rviz

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Update additional data: Note in this image the global map is also inverted as the text.
Not sure how they are related because the local frame is not inverted.

[image: image description]

I am showing inverted text on tf axis in rviz. The model and lazer data are not inverted as can be seen in the image below. What could be causing this? The image is not inverted this is actually how it shows in the rivz display.

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/93181/text-inverted-in-rviz/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2013-10-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The text inversion resolved on its own after switching between views when switching back the text appeared normal thereafter.

---

Originally posted by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) with karma: 713 on 2013-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0